# Calculate median value with template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, integer

I have this template getMedian() function, in which any data type is allowed. The detailed function is as below.

```
template<typename T>
T getMedian(T* inputArray, int arraySize)
{
    unique_ptr<T[]> sortArray(new T[arraySize]);
    copy(inputArray, inputArray + arraySize, sortArray.get());

    T medianValue;
    if (arraySize % 2)
    {
        nth_element(sortArray.get(), sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2, sortArray.get() + arraySize);
        medianValue = *(sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        nth_element(sortArray.get(), sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2, sortArray.get() + arraySize);
        T middle1 = *(sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2);
        nth_element(sortArray.get(), sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2 - 1, sortArray.get() + arraySize);
        T middle2 = *(sortArray.get() + arraySize / 2 - 1);
        medianValue = (middle1 + middle2) / 2;
    }
    return medianValue;
}
```

In the case that the input array is an **integer** array and the array size is an **even** number, the median should be the mean of the middle two numbers. The corresponding code is

```
medianValue = (middle1 + middle2) / 2;
```

However, in C++, the integer division would truncate to be the nearest small number (floor), instead of doing round. For example, middle1 = 10; middle2 = 5; medianValue = (middle1 + middle2) / 2 = 15 / 2 = 7. How can I make it to do the **round** instead of doing **floor**, and at the same time, **it will still keep the template structure**, i.e. not affect the case of input array is an float /double array?

I could just implement each case separately, but would like to see if there is a better way to do it or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(T)round((middle1 + middle2) / 2.0);`

Division with `2.0` will cast expression to `double`. Calling `round` after that will round it properly. And after that result will be casted to `T`.

**Edit:**

If floating point values are possible add one more template function for calculation of median:

```
template<typename T>
T median(T middle1, T middle2) {
    return (T)round((middle1 + middle2) / 2.0);
};

template<>
float median(float middle1, float middle2) {
    return (middle1 + middle2) / 2.0F;
};

template<>
double median(double middle1, double middle2) {
    return (middle1 + middle2) / 2.0;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This, however, will affect the float input array case. For example, if T is float, middle1 = 1.5, middle 2 = 2.7, then the result is supposed to be 2.1, but this try would be 2.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I could do in this way, as stated above "I could just implement each case separately, but would like to see if there is a better way to do it or not." But I guess this would be the case where an uniform implementation would not work well. Thank you for the response anyway!